# For loop through the slice and making the struct to be linked to a slice

Tags: for-loop, go, append

I need to do a for loop through the slice to display the values of the structs. I want to do something where household would be [0],food would be [1] and drink to be [2]

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type item struct {
    Category[3] int
    Quantity int
    Unitcost float64
}

categoryslice = []string{"Household","Food","Drink"}


func main() {
    shoppinglists := []shoppinglist{

        {
            Category: categoryslice[0],
            Quantity: 3,
            Unitcost: 1,
        },
        {
            Category: categoryslice[1],
            Quantity: 1,
            Unitcost: 3,
        },
    }

    fmt.Println("Shopping List Contents:")
    for _, x := range shoppinglists {
        fmt.Println("Category: ", x.Category," Quantity: ", x.Quantity, " Unit Cost: ", x.Unitcost)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `slice = append(slice, struct1, struct2, struct3)`

Comment: Please update the question by adding the code to the question directly and not only by posting a link to a remote resource. You can keep the link in addition to the code if you want to but make sure the code's here in the question, here on stackoverflow. See: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Now a comment on the code in the link: It looks like you want to loop over a struct's fields, this is not possible in Go using just the basic constructs, you would need to use the `reflect` package to be able to loop over a struct's fields, but I would advise against that as it can be quite complex, especially for someone "new to programming". Instead you should just access the fields directly using a [selector expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) e.g. `structValue.FieldName`.

Comment: …and in general, if you ever need to "loop over struct fields", do not use struct in the first place. Supposedly you was unfortunately infected by JavaScript which does not have struct types and its "objects" are arrays and are hash maps. Not in Go: the latter is a langauge with reasonably strict typing, and in such languages, `struct` types usually contain fields of different types and are not supposed to be iterated over—simply because it you want to iterate over something, that something is _a collection_ (of homogenuous values), not a pack of heterogenuous values.

Comment: …regarding your example, and supposing felds in Go structs could really be accessed by a (0-based) indices—what would be the semantics of appending the values of the "Categry" and "Items" fields (both of which are of `string` type) to the variable named "totals"—which sort of hints at that it contains the full sum of some set of values of quantities? I mean, are you sure you have thought your approach through?

Comment: @mkopriva you can link to [ask] by simply writing \[ask\] in the comment :) similarly to [mcve] by writing \[mcve\] and to the [edit] button using \[edit\].

Answer (score 0):

Not really recommended , but you can convert the `struct` into a `map` and iterate over the resulting `map`

add this method to your struct:

```
func (sl *shoppinglist) ToMap() map[string]interface{} {
    return map[string]interface{}{
        "category":  sl.Category,
        "items":     sl.Items,
        "quantity":  sl.Quantity,
        "unit_cost": sl.Unitcost,
    }
}
```

then iterate over each map in the slice like this

```
for _, e := range arr {
    for k ,v := range e.ToMap() {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", k, v)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

hope I helped :)

Comment: you can use the json encoder to map the struct to a `map[string]interface{}`. there is also github packages that does that (example: https://github.com/jinzhu/copier)